# Why doesn't Google Analytics Goals read encoded URLs?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am trying to set goals/funnels on Google analytics. A part of the URL is encoded. For example:

Step 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?q=5&title=Google%20Analytics%20Goals%20do%20not%20read%20encoded%20urls

Step 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?q=5&title=Google%20Analytics%20Goals%20do%20not%20read%20encoded%20urls%20at%20all

Step 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?q=5

Google Analytics only reads step 3 - it seems it does translate URL encoding.

I also tried to insert the URLs decoded on Google Analytics, but this didn't work either!

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the encoded URLs is your problem.  PLease explain how you setup the goal, what type of match, what (regex) value you are using, etc.

Comment: goal type: URL Destination
if I go to content/site/content/all pages and search for the URLs, I cannot find them. So, I have changed the %20F parts of the encoded url to / 
If I search that url on content/site/content/all pages I can find it only on advanced search and with the option "exactly matching".

Comment: So, I have changed match type to exact match. I can find all pages on content/site content/all pages, but some of the steps do not get recorded. What makes me think the problem is encoded URLs, is that 2/5 links are working and they do not have an encoded part

Comment: ...and that was the catch: replacing %20F to / made the thing work